# FlaskWTF csrf exempt not working...throws The CSRF token is missing exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I am setting up a stripe webhook that sends a post request to an endpoint on successful transaction.

My flask route is setup as below:

```
@app.route("/success", methods=["POST"])
@csrf.exempt
def payment_success_webhook():
```

It was working until last month but started throwing this exception:

```
wtforms.validators.ValidationError: The CSRF token is missing
```

The method does not even call any Forms.

Not sure on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade FlaskWTF if you've upgraded it during this month.